# How to create a submenu for Floating Action Button in Android Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design, submenu, floating-action-button

I want to create a **submenu** after click in my **floating action button** like this :

[image: SubMenu Fab]

I already know this Library :

> https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

But I want to create this with the **native FAB** of **android support design** :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
```

and

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible directly. `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` is a subclass of `ImageView` and it can't host children. You have to implement your own ViewGroup (a Vertical `LinearLayout` should be enough) and put the `FloatingActionButton` into it

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a library with the implemation of that ? The other view in your ViewGroup is also a FAB ? Because I think, I show in android developer webside that it's not a good practice to add multiple FAB in your view.

Comment: on github you can find couple of them. [Here](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) an  example. The material design guidelines state that you need this "View Group" if you have between 3 and 6 different actions. I'll try to look it up the page for you

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions)

Comment: In general scenario when there is only a FAB the snackbar automatically pushes the FAB and later its re-adjusted but when you use a FAB inside the linearLayout the snackbar overlaps the FAB. Did anyone face this issue ?